# Enqueue registered dependencies only when necessary

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script, wp-dependencies

I'm developing plugin where I want to load my dependency JS libraries only when the setting is enabled. The most correct way is to register all the scripts and styles I have and then enqueue my main script with dependencies, but I can't figure it out how to load them only when setting is enabled. Here's my current code:

```
function registerAssets() {
    wp_register_script('main', plugins_url('public/assets/js/script-main.js', $this->pluginFile), array('additionaljs', 'additionaljs2'), $this->version, true);
    wp_register_script('additionaljs', plugins_url('public/assets/js/additionaljs.js', $this->pluginFile), array(), $this->version, true);
    wp_register_script('additionaljs2', plugins_url('public/assets/js/additionaljs2.js', $this->pluginFile), array(), $this->version, true);
} // on action - init

function enqueueAssets() {
    wp_enqueue_script("main");
} // on action - wp_enqueue_scripts
```

so now I want to make them conditional, so only load dependency `additionaljs`, if setting is on. So I wrapped register function with if conditional:

```
if ($this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on') {
    wp_register_script('additionaljs', plugins_url('public/assets/js/additionaljs.js', $this->pluginFile), array(), $this->version, true);
}
```

Final code is this:

```
function registerAssets() {
    wp_register_script('main', plugins_url('public/assets/js/script-main.js', $this->pluginFile), array('additionaljs', 'additionaljs2'), $this->version, true);
    if ($this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on') {
        wp_register_script('additionaljs', plugins_url('public/assets/js/additionaljs.js', $this->pluginFile), array(), $this->version, true);
    }
    wp_register_script('additionaljs2', plugins_url('public/assets/js/additionaljs2.js', $this->pluginFile), array(), $this->version, true);
} // on action - init

function enqueueAssets() {
    wp_enqueue_script("main");
} // on action - wp_enqueue_scripts
```

But unfortunately it does not works and results in not loadingmain script at all. I want to load main.js with additionaljs2.js as dependency and only if $this->settings['additionaljs'] is on also load additionaljs.js as dependency..

So how can i do this?

Comment: That looks reasonable (except you're missing a closing bracket after `== 'on'`). Can you be more specific about how it's not working - do you get an error (on the page or in the logs), does the script never load even if the setting is set, can you print out the value of `$this->settings['additionaljs']` to make sure it's what you expect, etc.?

Comment: If your `main` script works without `additionaljs`, then `additionaljs` is not a dependency and shouldn't be registered as such.

Comment: @Rup missing bracket was just typo, so it's not the issue. The script loads and causing no errors, just main script is not loading at all. I want to load `main.js` with `additionaljs2.js` as dependency and only if `$this->settings['additionaljs']` is `on`, also load `additionaljs.js` as dependency.

Comment: @JacobPeattie `main.js` includes some code, which initializes `additional.js` and `additionaljs2.js` contents. They are JS plugins and I call them in `main.js`. So `main.js` will work, but part of it won't work without `additional.js` or `additionaljs2.js`.

Comment: But you're still declaring additionaljs as a dependency of main: `wp_register_script('main', ..., array('additionaljs', 'additionaljs2'), ...);` I think Jacob's point is that you shouldn't do that, e.g. by removing additionaljs when `$this->settings['additionaljs'] != 'on'`. Alternatively you could omit the dependencies altogether and just conditionally `wp_enqueue_script` the appropriate set based on your condition.

Comment: Right. If you make your script a dependency of another script, then that other script cannot load at all if the script is not present. If the 'dependency' is _optional_ then you should just enqueue it separately when required.

Comment: @Rup
@JacobPeattie `additionaljs.js` is dependency only when `$this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on'`. `main.js` works without `additionaljs.js`, but part of it requires `additionaljs.js`. I check if `$this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on'` in `main.js` by sending it as json, so the part which requires `additionaljs.js` only executes when `$this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on'`. So I want to load `additionaljs.js` as dependency only when `$this->settings['additionaljs'] == 'on'`

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to do. But in your final code you have `wp_register_script('main', plugins_url('public/assets/js/script-main.js', $this->pluginFile), array('additionaljs', 'additionaljs2'), $this->version, true);`. This bit: `array('additionaljs', 'additionaljs2')` means that main depends on additionaljs. You include that even when you're not going to supply additionaljs.

Comment: So you're hoping that when WordPress gets to writing out the script tag for main and it realises that it needs additionaljs (because you told it it still does) and can't find it, then it's going to write the script tag for main anyway. Which it may well still do, but it's possible it thinks it will avoid a script error / broken behaviour this way and omits main instead. I don't know my way around WP_Dependencies to verify this.

Comment: @Rup That's what I'm trying to avoid. So I want to load `additionaljs.js` only when the code block executes in `main.js` where it needs `additionaljs.js` as library. I need to tell WordPress somehow when is the time to load `additionaljs.js` as as dependency and when not.

Comment: You can't. That's not how dependencies work in WordPress. Just enqueue the `additionaljs.js` file separately when the WordPress PHP conditions match the circumstances under which additionaljs.js is needed.